# Horizontal scroll parallax cut off images

Tags: css

Someone can help me. I only have basic notions of html and css. I don't understand why the last top images are cut off at the end of the scroll, even though I remove max-width. The problem seems to be due to the parallax effect because when I remove the parallax code, the last image doesn't cut anymore and I have no idea how to fix it.

How can I keep the parallax effect without the last images being cut off?

```css
.salles-oeuvres {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    width: 100%;
    height: 425px;
    max-width: 960px;
    -webkit-perspective: 1px;
    perspective: 1px;
    background-image: url('../images/BGOeuvres.png');
}

.oeuvres-bottom {
    position: relative;
    /*padding-left: 50px;*/
    transform: translateZ(0);
    text-align: center;
    height: 0px;
    bottom: -60px;
}

.oeuvres-top {
    position: relative;
    /*padding-left: 100px;*/
    height: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
    top: -200px;
}

.oeuvres-div {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 83px;
}

.titre-top{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: -15px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.titre-bottom{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.oeuvres-div:hover{
    transition: all 200ms ease-out;
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px gray);
    
}

.oeuvres-div:hover .titre-top {
    display: block;

}

.oeuvres-div:hover .titre-bottom {
    display: block;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <title>New page</title>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="salles-oeuvres">
            <div class="oeuvres-top">
                <div class="oeuvres-div">
                    <div class="titre-top"><p>Titre oeuvre</p></div>
                    <a href="http://www.charlesdaudelin.org/"> <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/BateauIvre1943_T.jpg"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="oeuvres-div">
                    <div class="titre-top"><p>Titre oeuvre</p></div>                
                    <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/SansTitre1943_T.jpg"/>
                </div>
                <div class="oeuvres-div">
                    <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/NappeOrangee1948_T.jpg"/>
                </div>
                <div class="oeuvres-div">
                    <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/Hippo-chat1948_T.jpg"/>
                </div>
                <div class="oeuvres-div">
                    <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/LeMangeurDePasteques1948_T.jpg"/>
                </div>
                <div class="oeuvres-div">
                    <a href="http://www.charlesdaudelin.org/"> <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/SansTitre1948_T.jpg"/></a>
                </div>
                <div class="oeuvres-div">
                    <div class="titre-top"><p>Titre oeuvre</p></div>
                    <a href="http://www.charlesdaudelin.org/"> <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/BateauIvre1943_T.jpg"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="oeuvres-div">
                    <div class="titre-top"><p>Titre oeuvre</p></div>                
                    <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/SansTitre1943_T.jpg"/>
                </div>
                <div class="oeuvres-div">
                    <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/NappeOrangee1948_T.jpg"/>
                </div>
                <div class="oeuvres-div">
                    <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/Hippo-chat1948_T.jpg"/>
                </div>
                <div class="oeuvres-div">
                    <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/LeMangeurDePasteques1948_T.jpg"/>
                </div>
                <div class="oeuvres-div">
                    <a href="http://www.charlesdaudelin.org/"> <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/SansTitre1948_T.jpg"/></a>
                </div>              
            </div>
            <div class="oeuvres-bottom">
                <div class="oeuvres-div">
                    <div class="titre-bottom"><p>Titre oeuvre</p></div>
                    <a href="http://www.charlesdaudelin.org/"> <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/Antrenoir1969_T.png"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="oeuvres-div">
                    <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/CompositionNo1_1966_T.png"/>
                </div>
                <div class="oeuvres-div">
                    <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/EspaceSilenceEtNuit1966_T.png"/>
                </div>
                <div class="oeuvres-div">
                    <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/HabitantDesIles1946_T.png"/>
                </div>
                <div class="oeuvres-div">
                    <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/CompositionNo1_1966_T.png"/>
                </div>
                <div class="oeuvres-div">
                    <img src="https://www.pd6r.com/_DEV_charlesdaudelin/musees_test/images/Osten1989_T.png"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain your issue a bit further? Is it the background image, or just the images within the parallax scroll area? If it's the scroll area, you could remove the `max-width` property.

Comment: The last top images within the parallax at the end scroll cuts even if I remove max-width